# What are the cons of using inheritance to reduce duplicate code?

Tags: c++, inheritance, visual-c++

I'm currently writing a series of specialized data structure classes for a project I'm working on and I noticed that they all more or less share several completely identical properties and functions.

I could either just live with the duplicate code or let them inherit from a shared base class so that the total amount of code is reduced ALOT (which makes the whole thing much more maintainable). But alas I can't decide on what to do at this point.

I more or less understand the pros of the inheritance route but what are the cons when you compare it to having duplicate code lying around?

Which route is the more sane one to go for a 'long term' project?

Comment: You may also use composition.

Comment: Have you considered templates?

Comment: Look at inheritance as a *"every child is a parent"* relationship. This holds less often than one might think; for instance, a square may not be a rectangle as a rectangle can change the length of two opposing sites independent of the other two, a square can't. Usually, composition (and free functions!) is indeed the right way to avoid code duplication.

Comment: @Kerrek I actually am using templates already.

Comment: My problem is that my classes each have identical things such as sizes, pointers to data, functions returning said data and sizes etc but I dont know if inheritance is the right way to go.

@Jarod42 composition is an option but one I would prefer not to use since I wish to gettes/setters that return from other getters/setters and I really dislike syntax like this: list.sharedlist.size() :p

Comment: Do the thing that "makes the whole thing much more maintainable", Don't let silly ideals promoted by just as silly idealists, stand in the way of practical software engineering. Just say **pooh!** to the nonsense.

Comment: Private inheritance is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a design perspective, inheritance violates encapsulation. By inheriting from a class you link the new class with the implementation details of the parent, not all of which may be necessary for the particular implementation of the inheriting class.

For instance, let's say you have a class `vehicle`. This class has a number of private variables, e.g., `weight_`, `maxSpeed_`, and `fuelCapacity_`.

Now let's say you inherit to the class `bicycle`. The new class will have all the details associated with `fuelCapacity_`, even though they are not needed. This kind of thing can be quite a pain as the objects get more complex as changes which break the parent can also break the inheriting classes, even if they don't actually use that volatile part of the code.

A much safer choice is [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).